# How to get width and height React-pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

I am unable to get the width and height in react-pdf
[image]

I want to get the width and height in react-pdf without the debug attribute.

```
<View className="dynamic-height" debug>
    <View style={[membraneStyle.textHeader, { width: getRationVal(pageWidth) }]}>
        <SubLine lineWidth='10px' lineHeight='12' />
        <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 5 }}>Desalination \ Demineralization \ Membrane Separator (MEMS) Unit-Level Flow Summary</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={[membraneStyle.mainTable, { width: getRationVal(tablewidth) }]}>
        {createHeader(herder_val)}
        {createContent(items1, herder_val)}
    </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
handleLoadSuccess = async (pdfObject) => {
  // If you want to get the dimension for page 1 (1-indexed)
  const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
  console.log(page.width);
  console.log(page.height);
};

render() {
  <Document
    onLoadSuccess={handleLoadSuccess}
    // Other props
  />
};
```

Include this code to access the `onLoadSuccess` property. For instance, you can retrieve details such as page width, page height, and more when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the measure method to get the width and height of the View component.
you can modify your code to get the width and height of your View 
components.

import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Document, Page, Text, View, PDFViewer } from '@react- 
pdf/renderer';

function MyPDF() {
  const viewRef = useRef(null);
  let width = 0;
  let height = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewRef.current) {
      viewRef.current.measure((x, y, measuredWidth, measuredHeight) => {
        width = measuredWidth;
        height = measuredHeight;
        console.log(`Width: ${width}, Height: ${height}`);
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <PDFViewer>
      <Document>
        <Page size="A4">
          <View ref={viewRef} style={{ width: 200, height: 100 }}>
            <Text>My View</Text>
          </View>
        </Page>
      </Document>
    </PDFViewer>
  );
}

export default MyPDF;
```

Comment: I am getting some errors when I run this code.
`TypeError: viewRef.current.measure is not a function`